# Простая привязка данных к ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Уважаемые коллеги, пытаюсь привязать данные к ListView без behind-code(В смысле сама привязка).
Простая страница:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

behind-code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> collection;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //При навигации на страницу каким-либо образом получаем коллекцию. Например таким:
            collection = new ObservableCollection<string>( new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three"} );

            /* Вот так работает:
            MyList.ItemsSource = collection;
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что данные не привязываются. Если в behind-code явно прописать `ItemsSource` как в закомментированной строке, то все работает.
В гуглах нашел, что нужно прописать `this.DataContext = this;`, но по всей видимости, этого не достаточно. Чего еще не хватает в моем коде, чтоб работало без behind-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых у вас `collection` приватное.

Во-вторых для привязки нужно свойство, т.е:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> collection {get; private set}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло решить проблему. Добавлю еще, что `this.DataContext = this;` должно быть раньше инициализации, то есть надо поменять местами эти строчки.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад помочь

Answer (score 2):

`Binding` происходит к свойствам `DataContext`, а не к полям.